# Spine rig is glitching in Blender

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to create my own custom rig from scratch because I want to learn how to rig and create my own things, however, I keep running into a problem that I don't know what's causing it. It seems like a glitch.

For some reason, when I parent certain bones blender freaks out, and the rig starts spinning out of control.

I'm trying to control a head and spine rig with just three bones with copy rotation constraints which is working fine, however, the controller bones don't follow the armature which makes animating very confusing. But everytime I try parenting it to the armature, the glitch happens. I tried using the "Socket" method but the result is the same.

Is there a way of making the controller bones follow the armature without causing this glitch? I've tried searching but I only find information about the riggify addon which is useless to me.

The Blend file showing the issue:

[image]

Comment: have you checked that there were no circular dependency?

Comment: What's a circular dependency exactly?

Comment: for example if you give a Copy Rotation to a bone and choose its child as Target of this Copy Rotation

Comment: Okay, that's what I'm doing, and if that's what causing the glitch, then how can I parent the controllers to the Armature? How can I make them follow the armature without causing that?

Comment: parent all the controllers, pole targets and ultimate parent of the bone hierarchy to a root bone. I'm not sure what's your problem here as I'm not sure how your armature is supposed to work

Comment: That will make it confusing. I want the spine and head controlls to follow the head and spine of the character. So if I make the character bend, the controlls must follow the bending of the character. They won't do that if they are parented to the root bone.

Comment: You can't make a controller bone be controlled by a bone that it is supposed to control... but maybe show what you want to do with some drawings?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a similar result to this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUO8NA4Fh3A

Comment: That's a very sophisticated rig, and probably has a lot more than 3 bones.  Which part of the video are you trying to accomplish?